# how to extract 1st page after converting a pdf file to an image with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to convert pdf files to images, and I'm doing it with subprocess. Now I need a way to extract only the first page without having to convert all of the images. In this case, for example, I only need to convert "out-1.png."

[image]

What exactly do I need to get this done? Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import subprocess

PDFTOPPMPATH = r"C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin\pdftoppm.exe"
PDFFILE = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CO880\Click_CLI\Wikibot\report(7).pdf"
subprocess.Popen('"%s" -png "%s" out' % (PDFTOPPMPATH, PDFFILE))
```

**Note:** I have no intention to use pdf2image as I found a few errors with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the `'"%s" -png "%s" out'`, I discovered that I can pass extra parameters to get the first page.
The first parameter to pass is `-f <int>` which specifies the first page to convert; however, you must also pass `-l <int>` to specify the last page to convert. So eventually, I solved my problem by editing my last line to:
`subprocess.Popen('"%s" -png "%s" out -f 1 -l  1' % (PDFTOPPMPATH, PDFFILE))`